# <input type=TEXT value=$_POST['xx']> -> shows only first word of string as a value?

Tags: php

Could you please tell me what am i doing wrong? I have a very simple PHP code:

```
<?

echo "<form method=post action=test.php>";

if(isset($_POST['xx'])){

    $xx = $_POST['xx'];
    echo "<input type=text name=xx value=$xx>";

}
else{

    echo "<input type=text name=xx>";

}

echo "<input type=submit name=submit value=save>";
echo "<br />";
var_dump($xx);


?>
```

And when i send some string to 'xx', let' s say: - one two three - after sending it only first word of that string appears as a value - in that case it is "one".

var_dump result is

```
var_dump($xx);
string(13) "one two three"
```

It is even more strange when compared to result that i get on my notebook (with same XAMPP server) - in there i get only first letter of first word(!). Please tell me what to do about it as i have no idea... I tried input type text as well as textarea and that makes no difference.

I tried to look for similar problem in here, but found nothing that could help.

Comment: I just edited your code , you have missed single quotes ' ' in your `HTML`

Comment: @Exception Please don't do such edits. Firstly fixing code in this very question would make it non-answerable. Secondly, XHTML is no more, and quoting *every* attribute is silly.

Comment: @mario what do you mean that XHTML is no more? And why is it silly?

Comment: Nobody has ever used XHTML fully (namespace mixing). And in HTML5 self-closing `<br />` tags are as redundant, as are attribute quotes ***unless*** there are spaces or escape sequences in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `' '` in your HTML tags:

```
<?php

echo "<form method='post' action='test.php'>";

if(isset($_POST['xx'])) {
    $xx = $_POST['xx'];
    echo "<input type='text' name='xx' value='$xx'>";
} else {
    echo "<input type='text' name='xx'>";
}

echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='save'>";
echo "<br />";
var_dump($xx);
```